# 7zip - Open a compressed file without creating a permanent file

Tags: nautilus, 7zip

Suppose that I just want to open a file inside a `.7z` archive. What I'd like to have is that the system creates a temporary file somewhere and then open the file with the default application, pretty much what it happens when I double click a file inside a different compressed archive. Is it possible? Maybe with a nautilus plugin?

Answer (score 1):

the file-roller package provides a gui that can open 7zip files for you and extract them anywhere you choose, i'm guessing thats what you are using.

To extract a file you see in the listing right click and choose extract, you can then choose where to put it.

if you extract the files to /tmp they will be automatically deleted on reboot.

File-roller won't open the files for you but if you manually extract there is a show files button that will open a Nautilus window with them visible.

Another approach is to right click the archive and 'extract here' then you can click the files in Nautilus

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I mean, whenever I try to extract a 7z file using the `file-roller`, the process stops and I'm forced to kill it.

Comment: have you tried using the 7z command in the terminal to see if 7zip support is properly installed ?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly from the command line